# Buefy autocomplete in v-for

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, v-for, nuxtjs, buefy

I want to add a buefy autocomplete component iteratively using a v-for in NuxtJS.
Following Buefy documentation: https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete/ I ended up here:

```html
         <div
            v-for="(composition, index) in food_composition"
            :key="composition.id"
            class="box"
          >
            <b-field>
              <b-autocomplete
                <!-- What goes in the v-model? -->
                v-model="composition.nutrient.name"
                placeholder="Nutrient name"
                icon="magnify"
                :data="filteredNutrientArray"
                field="name"
                clearable
                @select="(option) => (selected = option)"
              >
              </b-autocomplete>
            </b-field>
          </div>
```

With filtered nutrient array being:

```js
filteredNutrientArray() {
      return this.groups.filter((option) => {
        return option.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(????)
      })
    },
```

According to buefy documentation, you structure your autocomplete by using as `v-model` a variable in the data; then your filtered array (`filteredNutrientArray`) will see if in the array of possible object, there is some that matches your typing. However if you put the autocomplete in a `v-for` loop, **How do you keep track of the user input?**

### SOLUTION:

(as per pj_studio answer):

I created a new component:

```html
<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-mutating-props -->
<template>
  <b-field>
    <b-autocomplete
      v-model="userInput"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      icon="magnify"
      :data="filteredDataArray"
      :field="field"
      clearable
      @select="(option) => (selected = option)"
    >
    </b-autocomplete>
  </b-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    field: {
      type: String,
      default: 'name',
    },
    userInput: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  computed: {
    filteredDataArray() {
      return this.data.filter((option) => {
        return option.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.userInput)
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the whole `<b-field></b-field>` in a child component, for example **foodCompositionAutocomplete.vue**.

Then in this child component you can track the user input via:

```js
<template>
    <b-field>
        <b-autocomplete
            v-model="userInput"
            :data="data">
        </b-autocomplete>
    </b-field>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['data'],
        data() {
            return {
                userInput: ''
            };
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Don't forget to pass the data via a prop on your child component.